# How to upload api to App Store from command line with Xcode 11?

Tags: ios

I want to upload my api (using Adobe Animate to make api) to apple store, how can I do that, please help me.

I am using command line to upload and Xcode 11 my code :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  @autoreleasepool {
      xcrun altool --upload-app -f Pass.ipa -u Myname -p Mypassword
  }

  return 0;
}
```

error in (xcrun altool)

I Tried to use application loader but it give me errors in icons, how can me upload my api to my apple store account.

Is there another way to upload the app?
 thanks for all.

Comment: You should probably fix those icon errors first.

Comment: Application Loader Give me errors but no error found in my Assets.car all icons true, because it I Tried to Upload by another way.

Comment: What errors does the application loader give you?

Comment: give me this errors :
ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."      
WARN: WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format.

Comment: I have Xcode 9 with Xcode 11 Both setup in my mac.

Comment: well, so add those icons to your asset catalog and you should be good.

Comment: I am rely Added it look at Contents.json
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-76@1x.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "76x76",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "icon-76@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
........
    {
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "filename" : "IOS Marketing.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "pre-rendered" : true
  }
}

Comment: الحمد لله
Thank you >>>>>>>>> for helping me.
I solved my problem in my asset catalog, Solution in bulid it as Generic iOS Device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**الحمد لله رب العالمين**

I solved my problem by using Application loader in uploading the IPA, And solved my problem of losing icons in asset catalog by This way :

1- choosing Generic iOS Device before building form Xcode.
2- go to product in Xcode and choose build.

> > > > > > > Look At Attachment Pic.

[Solve the problem of losing icons in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvHN4.jpg)